Symfony Access control not working despite correct role
I'm building a webapp with Symfony 6.3 and I have some problems with the access control part.
I have some urls in localhost/(locale)/dev/foo that should be accessible only by user with the role "HUNTER_DEV" or "HUNTER_ADMIN".
The problem is everytime I try to access to a url in localhost/(locale)/dev/foo I get an error 403 but when i dump my user or check it in the database the role is correct.
Here is my security.yaml

A part of the dump of my user

And the row in the database

I also tried things like but none seems to work

{ path: /dev, roles: HUNTER_DEV }
{ path: ^/dev, roles: HUNTER_DEV }

May be worthy mentionning that my users are connecting with SAML 2.0 Identity Provider (I'm using the bundle https://github.com/nbgrp/onelogin-saml-bundle)
Looks like I'm missing something probably basic but can't get it despite reading the documentation.

Ok. Looks like I can't RTFM after all. Missed the part where the doc explicitly says "The only rule is that every role must start with the ROLE_ prefix "

You could use custom roles without the ROLE_ prefix but you would need to create your own access voter
